# Is there a way to disable Windows automatically choosing folder templates?

Tags: windows-vista, windows-explorer

Windows Vista (and I guess Win 7 though I haven't used it) sometimes automatically applies templates to folders opened in Explorer based on their content.
E.g. a folder with photos automatically gets the columns "Date taken", "Tags", and "Rating".

Is there a way to disable the **automatic** application of this feature while still allowing manual customisation?
I really want to apply the "All Items" template to all folders on all drives, and have it stay that way except on a few folders that I manually customise.

The reason I want to disable the automatic behaviour is that it's often just wrong. I have folders with over 100 files where Windows has automatically applied a template based on the types of one or two of those files, and the template is wrong for everything else in the same folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

1. Run regedit
2. Go to: 
   `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\
           Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell`
3. Create Bags\Allfolder\Shell
4. Inside the "Shell" key, add a new "String Value", with the name "FolderType".
5. Modify the "FolderType" string setting the value: "NotSpecified".

Further specific instructions on http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/70819-windows-explorer-folder-view-settings.html

Comment: Thanks - the linked page looks like the answer and a whole lot more.

Comment: Can I still manually set a folder to be a "Picture" folder after this? I still want large thumbnails in there, and in general folders a details view. I just don't want Windows automatically changed the folder type.