# How to disable Windows XP folder templates?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer

There's similar question [answered](https://superuser.com/questions/149650/is-there-a-way-to-disable-windows-automatically-choosing-folder-templates) regarding Vista. And I'd like to disable automatic folder template recognition in Windows XP. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do the following:

1. Open a folder
2. Click `View`, and select the type of view you want to set as the default
3. Click `Tools`, `Folder Options`, `View`, and then select `Apply to All Folders`.